# Duvida - Criação e finalização de Threads em Delphi

Tags: delphi

Bom dia,

Estou criando um sistema de Chat em Delphi, e estou utilizando thread para renderizar o histórico de mensagens sem que a aplicação trave. Diante várias pesquisas, achei uma coisa aqui, outra ali e adaptei a minha necessidade, porém, não faço ideia se finalizei e limpei a mesma da memória, e preciso fazer com que ao terminar a execução a mesma se encerre por completo, até porque esse sistema de chat vai ser integrado a um outro sistema, e estou tentando ao máximo evitar um consumo exagerado.

Eis o código teste que estou utilizando - primeira vez que utilizo threads, não sei nem se estou utilizando a mesma de maneira correta:

```
TThreadRenderMsgs = class(TThread)
private
{ Private declarations }
   idPrivForm : Integer;
   procedure atualizaPanel;
protected
{ Protected declarations }
   procedure Execute; override;
public
{ Public declarations }
   constructor Create (const CreateSuspended : Boolean);
end;

constructor TThreadRenderMsgs.Create(const CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
   Self.FreeOnTerminate  := True;
   inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TThreadRenderMsgs.atualizaPanel;
var
   mensagem : String;
begin
   mensagem := 'Teste';
 DM_SocketCliente.formClientPrivMsg[idPrivForm].chrChat.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('addSendMessage(''' + mensagem + ''')', 'about:blank', 0);
end;

procedure TThreadRenderMsgs.Execute;
var
   i : Integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to 20 do
   begin
     if Terminated then
       Break;
     Synchronize(Self.atualizaPanel);
     Sleep(1000);
   end;
   Terminate;
end;

procedure TfrmClientePrivMsg.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   threadRenderMsgs : TThreadRenderMsgs;
begin
   threadRenderMsgs := TThreadRenderMsgs.Create(True);
   threadRenderMsgs.Start;
   threadRenderMsgs.idPrivForm := idMyPrivForm;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas notas:

- Devias passar o form no Create da thread em vez de 'cravares' o id. Ainda por cima fazes o .Start(); antes de lhe dares o idPrivForm. Com algum azar, tens erros na thread, se ela passar o Execute antes de lhe dares o idPrivForm.
- Penso que tambem te falta verificar se a thread ainda esta a executar quando fechas o programa. Se calhar era melhor usares um TEvent em vez do Sleep
- Se é realmente apenas isto que queres fazer, também podes usar a TTask e poupar muito codigo

(Essa thread termina sozinha ao fim de 20s, é suposto?)

Comment: obrigado, dei umas pesquisadas e cheguei a conclusão que o TTask já supria minhas necessidades.